# Assinging unsigned long (from C++) to long (Java) in CORBA client/server app?

Tags: java, c++, type-conversion, corba

On servers side I have function which returns unsigned long value (server is written in C++), lets say:

```
class Sth {

private:
   CORBA::ULong u;
public:
   CORBA::ULong get()
   {
    return this.u;
   }

};
```

How to assign (on clients side) value returned from server to variable? I mean, theres no unsigned long in Java ... Is it possigle to assign it to long? Like this:

```
// corba client stuff
long var = server_obj.get();
```

will it be ok?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The text refers to unsigned long, but the C++ code uses Long, and the Get method returns void.

Comment: @Éric Malenfant: OK, I edited my code

Comment: Of course you can map the return value to a long, but the corba stuff will have converted it already to int before.

Answer (score 4):

You have to look at the IDL mapping for that. `unsigned long` of OMG IDLs mapped to `CORBA::ULong` in C++ and to `int` in Java. Refer [IDL to Java Mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/mapping/jidlMapping.html) and [IDL to C++ Mapping](http://www.triodia.com/staff/michi/advanced_corba/chapter_6.pdf) for more on CORBA language mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the BigInteger class in java instead of long. Theres not any other convenient way to make that conversion.

Comment: ULong is mapped to int in Java

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, you know that unsigned long will never exceed 2^31, a.k.a. MAX_LONG. Then using long in Java is okey.

In some other cases, the actual values have little meaning, as long as they are unique, e.g. some kind of handle. Again, you can use jlong.

In yet other cases, Java is only used as an intermediate, and if conversion from C to Java to C is correct, you don't care that there was a signed/unsigned mismatch on the way.

But if none of the above exceptions hold, you should use BigInteger or reinvent it (*bad idea*)

Comment: ULong is mapped to int in Java

Comment: My understanding is that @mazix will implement the Android side himself, not reusing some Java CORBA adapter.

Comment: Which android? Building CORBA adapter and asking basic CORBA questions doesn't fit.

Comment: Sorry, s/Android/client/. My fault.